# Python - how to sleep or hibernation computer

Tags: python, sleep, shutdown

How to put to sleep or hibernation computer? 
I know i can shutdown with os.system("shutdown") but i dont want complete system shutdown. 
It is possible to to this?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. But the answer is `"shutdown /h"` for hibernation.

Comment: `shutdown /?` in the command line to see the available options.

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
os.system("shutdown.exe /h")
```

Taken from [Suspend / Hibernate pc with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517496/suspend-hibernate-pc-with-python)

(If someone can mark this question as a duplicate, that would be appreciated)

Comment: Why would you post an answer if you know it's a duplicate of another question o.o?

Comment: @MooingRawr Sorry, new-ish to using Stack Overflow so I wasn't aware I could flag something as a duplicate until after I answered. Would it be better to delete my response?