# time.sleep does not work for multithreaded

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, sleep, pywin32

I was trying to multithread the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39360397/7099900) for ["Suspend / Hibernate pc with python"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7517496) provided by [Ronan Paixão](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3754432/ronan-paix%c3%a3o) when I find that `time.sleep()` does not suspend the thread that run `pywin32` module.

**>>> Warning! The following code will put Windows to sleep <<<**

```
def suspend(buffer, hibernate=False):
    '''Puts Windows to Suspend/Sleep/Standby or Hibernate.

    Parameters
    ----------
    buffer: string, for time.sleep()
    hibernate: bool, default False
        If False (default), system will enter Suspend/Sleep/Standby state.
        If True, system will Hibernate, but only if Hibernate is enabled in the
        system settings. If it's not, system will Sleep.

    Example:
    --------
    >>> suspend()
    '''
    print('before sleep') 
    sleep(float(buffer))
    print('after sleep')
    # Enable the SeShutdown privilege (which must be present in your
    # token in the first place)
    priv_flags = (win32security.TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES |
                  win32security.TOKEN_QUERY)
    hToken = win32security.OpenProcessToken(
        win32api.GetCurrentProcess(),
        priv_flags
    )
    priv_id = win32security.LookupPrivilegeValue(
        None,
        win32security.SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME
    )
    old_privs = win32security.AdjustTokenPrivileges(
        hToken,
        0,
        [(priv_id, win32security.SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED)]
    )

    if (win32api.GetPwrCapabilities()['HiberFilePresent'] == False and
            hibernate == True):
        import warnings
        warnings.warn("Hibernate isn't available. Suspending.")
    try:
        windll.powrprof.SetSuspendState(not hibernate, True, False)
    except:
        # True=> Standby; False=> Hibernate
        # https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/aa373206(v=vs.85).aspx
        # says the second parameter has no effect.
        #        ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetSystemPowerState(not hibernate, True)
        win32api.SetSystemPowerState(not hibernate, True)

    # Restore previous privileges
    win32security.AdjustTokenPrivileges(
        hToken,
        0,
        old_privs
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target=suspend, args=("10")).start()
```

The `print` function did waited for `time.sleep()`, but the Windows was immediately put to sleep.
What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the buffer argument in the call to `Thread` incorrectly, so it's only `sleep`ing for 1.0 second. You need to add a comma `,` at the end of value for the `args` keyword argument like this:

```
.
.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target=suspend, args=("10",)).start()
```

Comment: You are right. I just realised that the `args` is a tuple. Thank you very much.

Comment: I was a little surprised myself, because in most cases you don't need to put the comma in when passing one as an argument, but if the first argument is a string it's—apparently—necessary. Personally, I always put it in because it doesn't hurt and is more explicit. Question: Why are you passing this argument as a string instead of a float in the first place?

Comment: Right. I was surprised too. The `buffer` were used in many other instances as string so I figured that I would just parse it to float when it was needed. Besides that, it doesn't hurt if I accidentally pass in int or float as the argument.